Is it possible to add new tests that I wrote to the HLK playlist file?
I want to add a custom test for testing the driver. Can I add a new test to the playlist file(xml)?
In the playlist file I downloaded from Microsoft, I see that every test has an ID. I also noticed that there is an existing directory in the Hardware Lab Kit directory called "tests." What steps should I take to add a new test there and include it in the playlist file I have? Where should I store the ID and details of the test?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, you can add new tests to the HLK playlist file. Just update the playlist XML with the test details, making sure everything is correctly formatted. After making changes, double-check the playlist to ensure it works properly.

I see that every test in the playlist file has an ID for matching the test with the HLK test database, as we can see here, for example:


So, I'm trying to understand what I need to do in order to register my test? Which files do I need to create for these tests is it can be a powershell script only or something else?
thanks!
